# Where can I follow what appBuilder is doing?

Tags: logging, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm working with appBuilder/procedure editor, release 11.6 (not a Studio IDE).

Apparently, one of my colleagues has modified a window file (`*.w`) in Notepad++, compiled it and it was working fine. When I try to compile this file, there is also no problem.

However, when I try to open the file in appBuilder, I get error message 11678, followed by 12370, followed by 142, and those two last error messages keep on going on and on, it looks like an infinite loop.

I've been checking the files "compile.log", "listing.txt" (compilation listing) and "XRef.txt", but it seems that none of those files is modified while opening a file in the appBuilder.

The fact that those error messages appear, means that the appBuilder is doing something.

I'm not looking at the solution of this particular error (11678), I'm more interested in some logging, which might enable me to follow what the appBuilder is doing, so that I can learn what the appBuilder is doing with what part of the code, so that I can solve my issue, but it seems that currently the appBuilder is not logging anything.

Does anybody know if appBuilder logging exists and in case yes, how I can enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the AppBuilder is just ABL code running in an AVM, you can add the following to your startup shortcut or add it to a pf file reference by your startup shortcut:

`-clientlog mylogfile.log -logentrytypes 4gltrace:2`

This will write all calls to mylogfile.log. If you need more logging, you can increase the logging level to `4gltrace:3` this will then also log all return values from function calls.

If you have `-debugalert` enabled you can also start the debugger to see what is going on.

Documentation on:

- [-logentrytypes](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-startup-and-parameter-reference-117/page/Log-Entry-Types-logentrytypes.html)
- [-clientlog](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-startup-and-parameter-reference-117/page/Client-Logging-clientlog.html)

Note that you will need to use the [-zn](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P61218) startup parameter for debugging / logging internal stuff.

Comment: It seems not to be working completely: I see the logfile, being created, and it starts with some lines, containing logging level (2) and log entry types (4GLTrace:3), but the next entry is the error message I mentioned in my question. In order to learn how it works, I tried adding a command like `&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-CODE-BLOCK _CUSTOM _MAIN-BLOCK WIN-DATA 
LOG-MANAGER:WRITE-MESSAGE("begin main-block").` at the beginning of the main-block of a `*.w` file which opens without problems, but I don't see that entry in my logfile.

Comment: https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-troubleshoot-applications-117/page/Hidden-procedure-files.html

I thought there was a startup parameter to override this behavior (-z) but cannot find any reference at the moment.

Comment: Found something - https://community-archive.progress.com/forums/00018/58282.html - use -zn

Comment: And once you know what your are looking for - https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P61218

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the real issue is that the structure of the program has probably been broken.  The AppBuilder expects certain things in certain places so it can appropriately parse a program, particularly with regard to the Section Editor and linking code sections to the GUI development framework.  Something about those structure tags was probably altered in a way to deviate from the assumptions in the AppBuilder's parsing of that source code file.